# Force permission on Google OAuth consent screen

Tags: frontend, google-oauth

I am currently developping an app which allows Google sign-in. We are asking permissions to get access to the users contacts (for invitation) and agenda (to create events).

Our app has been validated by Google a few weeks ago.

The main issue is that we would prefer to require our users to grant permission to access their accounts during the sign-in process, but we have a (rather long) list of checkboxes that the user must manually click on, which is a really bad UX.

[image: Current behavior]

I understand the privacy reason for that behavior, but I know that it is somehow possible, since I've tested that on another app myself (see below)

[image: Google consent screen working as we would like]

Google support is non existant on that subject, and the resources I found here or somewhere else are either deprecated or doesn't answer the question.

Have some of you encountered the same problem and fixed it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These checkboxes are due to the [granular account permission](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html) change added in 2018. They are there to give the user the option to accept or reject your request, and can not be turned off.

You can read up on this in the original blog post. [this Google Developers blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html)

Comment: I've already seen such answers, but the fact is that I saw hours ago the behavior that I want, so there must be a way to achieve that